# Is there a order to see the type of file in Mac?

Tags: osx

In my mac, I cd to the `/usr/bin/`,and list the files under the directory:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

You know in Mac there is no color to distinct the type of the files.
I don't know the file is folder or text file or what else.

So, is there a order to show the file's type? Or how can we distinct the files type?

Comment: Does `ls -GF` work for you?

Comment: @fd0 yes, it works, thank you. bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ls -la | grep '^d'` to get a list of all directories in your current working directory

`ls -la | grep '^[^d]'` to get a list of all "files"(not directory) in current working directory

what `ls -la` shows starts with d is a directory.Common files starts with -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `file` command might be of use. It looks at the first few bytes of the file and takes a (pretty good) guess at what it is.

Answer (score 0):

You may install GNU coreutils on macOS to get GNU `ls`. There are several ways of doing this, including using HomeBrew, MacPorts, Fink or NetBSD's pkgsrc. Some of these may install the GNU utilities with a `g` prefix to distinguish them from the utilities in the base system (i.e. GNU `ls` would be installed as `gls`).

It's also possible to define a simple alias for `ls` that just adds the `-F` flag:

```
alias ls="ls -F"
```

This will cause some types of files to be annotated with a character at the end of their filenames, e.g. `@` for symbolic links, `/` for directories, `*` for executable files, etc.

The manual for `ls` will tell you more.